# Locate 'targeted' data in one spreadsheet document and import it into another

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to find out 'how' to use collected form data to retrieve targeted data from a separate Google spreadsheet (source) and insert it into the response spreadsheet (target).

The [google form is here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1exCI-NyWH97I7d-b9T99Ng5RH5GUDiAS6s6bxSFddmY/viewform), the [target spreadsheet is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoV45G_-cBI0dGhlUjh3RkE3LWRCelNvTGtWNzRodXc&usp=sharing), and the [source spreadsheet is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoV45G_-cBI0dGZsUU9VbnFFb3BwQmItSmR6cDR4aUE&usp=sharing).

The goal is to locate student data in the 'source' spreadsheet based on the Student ID# and Period that is submitted via the Google from. Then pull the student name and correct period teacher (name & email) from the 'source' into the 'target'.

I originally thought I would use Vlookup function, but then I realized I can not because the source spreadsheet and the target spreadsheet a separate documents. Now I believe the Query function is what I need to use, but I'm not sure how to structure the function.

**So far, I have this, but it doesn't work 'yet'**

```
QUERY(importRange("0AoV45G_-cBI0dGZsUU9VbnFFb3BwQmItSmR6cDR4aUE&usp", "Sheet1!A1:G"), "select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col2='data1'", 1)
```

**I'm really confused on this part**

```
"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col2='data1'", 1)
```

I only want to copy two columns based on the student ID # (student fname, student lname) and then two columns based on the period (teacher, teacher email).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Import all students: I would import all of the source sheet into a new sheet in the  destination spreadsheet using importRange, then use VLookUp as was your plan.

I am not sure Query will work in the way you want. I.e. there is no way to merge data from two ranges. So you would end up with a ImportRange for every student.
ImportRange: "Note: The limit on the number of ImportRange functions per spreadsheet is 50."

Eddy.

Spreadsheet forumlas that build web applications

Comment: Eddy, do you know if I can accomplish my goal using Google Apps Script?

Comment: Should work. What you want is known as a "JOIN" (in SQL). The google apps script gallery has "vmerge" that is close, and would give a starting point.